# Several plots in one plot

Tags: r

In R I want to plot say these vectors in one plot.

```
a <- c(1,2,5,4)
b <- c(10,2,3,4)
d <- c(5,4,6,8)
```

To plot these I type

```
plot(a, col="blue")
points(b, col="green")
points(d, col="orange")
```

Now I get not all points and that is confusing. The plot is simply not 'big' enough to capture all points. Is there a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `matplot` :

```
m<-cbind(a,b,d)
matplot(m,type='l',col=c('blue','green','orange'),lty=1,lwd=1)
```

[image]

An other option is to specify the limits of the y-axis :

```
plot(a, col="blue",ylim=c(0,10))
points(b, col="green")
points(d, col="orange")
```

[image]

You can of course change the type of lines, width, labels, ... for both options.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that I could specify plot with ylim and xlim.

Comment: or in a more general situation you can use `ylim = range(c(a, b, d))`.